# a: visited {text decoration: none} not working in Firefox

Tags: css, hyperlink, visited

I have an image that is a link. When I click on it it sends me somewhere and then if I click back to return on that page that image has a 1px dotted blue border around itself. Furthermore, if I click on it and hold that border becomes red. This is really bad looking and I cannot find a way to delete that border.
I've tried with

```
a:visited {text-decoration: none}
a:active {text-decoration: none}
```

and with:

```
a:visited img{text-decoration: none}
a:active img{text-decoration: none}
```

with no effect.
By the way, this border does not appear in chrome.

Here is my css code regarded to that image:

```
#back_to_photos{
float:right;
position: relative;
margin-top:-238px;
margin-right: 40px;

}
a:visited {text-decoration: none}
a:active {text-decoration: none}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should use border: none on the image or outline: none.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixed your problem you could thank the poster by marking their answer as Answered.  (e.g. @alex or @Bojangles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/) describes how to do so. Namely, putting `outline: 0;` in your `a:visited` CSS should do the trick.

`text-decoration` only deals with things like underlines and strikethroughs. The problem you're encountering is with `outline` that is put around clicked/focused links to tell the user that's what they're hovering over.

Do note that if you remove the outline it won't be apparent where the user is if they're navigating your page with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is something wrong with the order of your rules (don't know these are the only styles mentioned in your example). What you could try is to 'force it' by using **!important**:

```
a {text-decoration: none !important;}
```

Hopes it helps.

Comment: The OP's issue isn't to do with `text-decoration` but `outline` instead. Please see mine/alex's answers for more :-)

Comment: O, i see, sorry, please forgive me it is sunday. But he can try {border:none;} instead.

Comment: `border: none` won't work either because it's not an actual border per  se; it's an outline, hence the `outline: none` property actually getting rid of it.

Comment: As regards the OP's rule for `a:visited`, `!important` won't override the fact that browser don't allow the `visited` selector to be used for styling `text-decoration` for [for privacy reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

Answer (score 2):

the solution for your problem is this:

```
a:link, a:link:hover { text-decoration: none }
```

hope it helps.

more info on: [squarefree.com/styles](http://www.squarefree.com/userstyles/)

Comment: Note that the page you link to is from 2007, before browsers prevented the `:visited` selector from being used for `text-decoration` [for privacy reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector). (You don't use `text-decoration`, but it's worth pointing that out since the OP tried to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `outline: none`.

Be careful though, hiding the outline can lead to usability issues, especially with those users who navigate with the keyboard.